# ASP.NET call a function in code behind with LinkButton

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton, onclientclick

I have this LinkButton here

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="EditBtn" CssClass="LinkButton" Text="Edit" Width="45px" OnClientClick="Profiles_Edit" CommandName="edit" />
```

and I am trying to call this function in my code behind

```
protected void Profiles_Edit(Object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //do something
    }
```

but when I click on the button....nothing happens. My LinkButton is inside an ItemTemplate, which is inside a ListView, which is inside a ContentTemplate, which is inside a UpdatePanel....

What is wrong with the way I am calling it?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 2):

`OnClientClick` is for specifying the name of the JavaScript function on the client browser.

To call the server-side event, use `OnClick`.

Also, you may not need the `CommandName` attribute in this situation. It isn't clear where this `LinkButton` resides. If it's in a container like a `ListView`, you would handle it differently.